# Is there a way to completely remove the breadcrumbs in the Control Panel?

Tags: control-panel, zoo

I'm trying to make the Control Panel as stripped down as possible for clients who get confused easily. Is there a way to completely remove the breadcrumbs from the Control Panel? I see various add-ons to manage breadcrumbs, but I don't see a way to completely remove them. I'm using Zoo Admin for my custom menu, but one of my clients gets confused when they see the breadcrumbs below the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a few ways to go about it. First, the easier way, is to see if you can find a Control Panel theme that better matches what you're looking to do.

https://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=theme&addon_version_support=ee2

Search around, perhaps there's already a nice simple theme that will work for you. If not, the better answer is to create you're own theme.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_styles/#customizing-the-control-panel-theme

And finally, the less than smart answer; just hide the control by editing a core `_shared` file. You want to edit this file `system/expressionengine/views/_shared/breadcrumps.php` and go ahead and add this HTML attribute to the div with `id="breadCrumb"`:

```
style="visibility: hidden;"
```

Comment: Highly recommend you do NOT modify the core file breadcrumbs.php as this will get overwritten on EE update.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Control Panel CSS/JS](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) add-on.

Then add the following CSS:

```
#breadCrumb { display:none; }
```

Or for slightly better result:

```
#breadCrumb { height:22px; }
#breadCrumb ol { display:none; }
```